# Using a bash script to toggle through a scalable variable

Tags: bash

I have a bash script within which I wish to toggle through values of a particular variable. The minimum value is 0.05 and the maximum value is 0.5. The step size is 0.05, making 10 values in all. How, as part of a for loop, would I implement this stepwise incrementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for n in $(seq 0.05 0.05 0.5); do
    echo $n
done
```

From the man page for `seq(1)`:

> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> seq [OPTION]... LAST
> seq [OPTION]... FIRST LAST
> seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> Print numbers from FIRST to LAST, in steps of INCREMENT.